# Promtail is not able to send logs to Grafana

Tags: grafana-loki

Promtail is giving me this error. It was working fine till yesterday.

```
level=warn ts=2022-03-31T17:57:10.266631785Z caller=client.go:349 component=client host=loki-gateway msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 error="Post \"http://loki-gateway/loki/api/v1/push\": dial tcp: lookup loki-gateway on 10.100.0.10:53: no such host"
```

Loki logs:

```
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:05.469740401Z caller=compactor.go:263 msg="compactor is ACTIVE in the ring"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:05.487108207Z caller=scheduler.go:629 msg="scheduler is ACTIVE in the ring"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:05.487260134Z caller=module_service.go:64 msg=initialising module=querier
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:05.487330504Z caller=module_service.go:64 msg=initialising module=query-frontend
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:05.48759267Z caller=loki.go:355 msg="Loki started"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:08.487541256Z caller=worker.go:205 msg="adding connection" addr=172.17.48.142:9095
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:08.487819299Z caller=scheduler.go:663 msg="this scheduler is in the ReplicationSet, will now accept requests."
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:10.470544823Z caller=compactor.go:305 msg="this instance has been chosen to run the compactor, starting compactor"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:10.470639278Z caller=compactor.go:332 msg="waiting 10m0s for ring to stay stable and previous compactions to finish before starting compactor"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:58:15.48798601Z caller=frontend_scheduler_worker.go:100 msg="adding connection to scheduler" addr=172.17.48.142:9095
level=info ts=2022-03-31T17:59:05.346176281Z caller=table_manager.go:171 msg="uploading tables"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:00:05.348704439Z caller=table_manager.go:171 msg="uploading tables"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:01:05.345773048Z caller=table_manager.go:171 msg="uploading tables"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:02:05.345744777Z caller=table_manager.go:171 msg="uploading tables"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:03:05.34667879Z caller=table_manager.go:171 msg="uploading tables"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:03:05.346699401Z caller=table_manager.go:207 msg="syncing tables"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:03:05.355327332Z caller=checkpoint.go:617 msg="starting checkpoint"
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:03:05.355872498Z caller=checkpoint.go:342 msg="attempting checkpoint for" dir=/data/loki/wal/checkpoint.000000
level=info ts=2022-03-31T18:03:05.358364448Z caller=checkpoint.go:504 msg="atomic checkpoint finished" old=/data/loki/wal/checkpoint.000000.tmp new=/data/loki/wal/checkpoint.000000
```

Comment: Hey mate, could you provide detailed info about your config, or maybe a Pastebin, or something that allows us to replicate the error :thinking:

Answer (score 6):

If you use [promtail](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/promtail) helm chart, pay attention to [values.yaml](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/promtail/values.yaml) configuration.

They have changed the structure:

old ([v4.2.1](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/promtail-4.2.1/charts/promtail/values.yaml#L348))

```yaml
config:
  lokiAddress: http://<LOKI_DOMAIN>:3100/loki/api/v1/push
```

new ([v5.0.0+](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/promtail-6.0.2/charts/promtail/values.yaml#L356))

```yaml
config:
  clients:
    - url: http://<LOKI_DOMAIN>:3100/loki/api/v1/push
```

Comment: Was the solution for me